# html css div layout with text area expanding vertically

Tags: html, css

With my limited knowledge of html/css I am attempting to create a div layout for a form as shown in the image below:

[image]

However I ended up making a  bit of a messs of it, so if I could get some guidance on the best way to implement this div layout?

Here is my attempt with html/css, but not quite right as I need to get input boxes/button next to their corresponding labels as shown in the image, but also I'm not even sure if my code to the whole approach to replicating the div layout from the image is correct practice:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-child {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.flex-child:first-child {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>The td rowspan attribute</h1>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-child">
    Label

    <div class="flex-child">
      Label
    </div>

    <div class="flex-child">
      Label
    </div>
    <div class="flex-child">
      <textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="flex-child">
    Label
    <div class="flex-child">
      <textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="flex-child">
    Text
    <div class="flex-child">
      Label
      <div class="flex-child">
        Button

      </div>

    </div>
```

You will notice I would like to have 2 text area boxes and should be able to expand vertically when the user drags down.

I appreciate any help on this, Thanks.

Comment: `display: flex` only affects direct child elements.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you want to do properly, but looks like you want to limit textarea to expand horizontally. If it is then try `style="max-width:200px"` in **textarea** field

Comment: I'm trying to layout labels with input/text area boxes in my div layout as I have tried to demonstrate in the image supplied. Thanks